# How to draw Square wave in highchart

Tags: highcharts

i want to draw square wave in highchart.please see the attached file [image]below

Below image show the square wave in the graph . i want to draw like that in highchart

Answer (score 4):

You can use line series with defined `step` parameter

http://jsfiddle.net/k5JEB/
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.step